# Search two big files and delete unfound values

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary

I have a query file and subject file. Query file is a tab delimited table:

```
id  value
1_A X
1_T Y
2_A Z
2_C AA
2_S B
```

Subject file is a tab-delimited cluster file:

```
line1   H_2 1_A
line2   1_T 2_A
line3   2_C H_3
line4   2_S
```

My aim is to read the subject file line by line and search for the presence of each element in query file. I will remove the element, if it is not found in query file. For example my output will be:

```
line1 1_A
line2 1_T   2_A
line3 2_C
line4 2_S
```

As you can see, in first line H_2 is not present in query file, hence removed form output list.

I wrote the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

query = pd.read_csv('query.txt', sep='\t')
print query
dic = query.set_index('id')['value'].to_dict()
print dic.keys()

new_tmp = []
with open('subject.txt') as sbjt:
    sub = sbjt.readlines()
    for eachline in sub:
        tmp = eachline.strip('\n').split('\t')
        print tmp
        for i in range(1,len(tmp)):
            if tmp[i] in dic.keys():
                new_tmp.append(tmp[0])
                new_tmp.append('\t')
                new_tmp.append(tmp[i])
        new_tmp.append('\n')

print new_tmp
outfile = open('test.txt', 'w')
for item in new_tmp:
    print >> outfile, item
```

The issues with this code are:

1. The output is written in sequence, i.e each element in a line and not as specified in the code.
2. The example files are small and hence it runs faster. However, my real file has 300k dict.keys and subject file has 35k entries. Is there a way to speed this up with an alternative ?

Thanks in advance,

AP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Performance issue

that

```
if tmp[i] in dic.keys():
```

works but you're not really using the dictionary search, specially in python 2.7 where `keys()` returns a list so search is `O(N)` (much better for a dictionary search)

Do that instead, simpler & faster:

```
if tmp[i] in dic:
```

#### Formatting issue

You're creating one line per item. Each element `new_tmp` should represent a line, not a token.

From your comment, you seem not to need `tmp[0]` every time (I copied the erroneous code), so it can be done with a generator comprehension instead of a loop, even better (no temporary list is created to create the line).

```
line = "\t".join(c for i,c in enumerate(tmp) if i==0 or c in dic)
```

(always take first item or if is in dictionary, avoid indexed access, don't create a `list()`: much faster)

To sum it up, to create 1 line with all items do this:

```
tmp = eachline.strip('\n').split('\t')
if tmp:  # list not empty
    # add a line with all matched tmp items separated by \t
    line = "\t".join(c for i,c in enumerate(tmp) if i==0 or c in dic)
    new_tmp.append(line+"\n")
```

Comment: Ok. Can you comment on the writing method ? Why I get it one line each, though I have specified \t & \n in append ?

Comment: Great ! It works... but I had put the toks.append(tmp[0]) before entering for loop and removed \n new_tmp.append(). Else, it is writing tmp[0] for every match  & introduces a blank line after every entry !

Comment: See my edit. If you don't need first item each time, it can even be done in a simpler & faster way.